# Resample 2D Array from 2x2 to 4x4

Tags: java, c#, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to re-sample a 2D array from 2x2 `data` to 4x4 `newdata`

Original Source 2D Array `data`:

[image]

What I am looking for in `newdata`

[image]

So far I have tried it as below;

```
public class Test {
    static int[][] data = new int[2][2];
    static int[][] newdata = new int[4][4];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    data[0][0] = 00;
    data[0][1] = 01;
    data[1][0] = 10;
    data[1][1] = 11;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

// I NEED LOGIC HERE TO FILL newdata 2D ARRAY as a re-sampled output

        }
    }

}

}
```

Implementation can be in any language e.g. c++, php, c#, java etc.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried anything in your logic yet, because your try just involves initializing the first array

Comment: @KevinEsche I tried creating logic at iteration of each index, but couldn't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loops to :

```
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
            {
                newdata[k][l] = data[k/2][l/2];
            }
        }
```

Comment: The outer 2 ```for``` statements (i and j) are redundant.